# Mysql Order By VS. Node.js sort

Tags: mysql, node.js, sorting

I'm retrieving a list of rows from a mysql database and will need to sort the data. Is it less stress on my server to do the sort via mysql 'order by' clause, or to sort the data with node.js sort()? Which is more efficient?

Comment: Did you try just benchmarking it with real-world data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic answer as to which sorting is more efficient. It depends on a lot of circumstances.

There are cases when you **must** sort in mysql. For example, when you would like to get the top N record from a table - there is no point of retrieving the entire table into node.js and do the sorting there.

There are cases when mysql may sort records slower using filesort, this is when you may consider sorting in node.js instead. `explain` statement will tell you if sorting is done via filesort in mysql. Filesorts can usually sped up by indexes, but you may not eant to add any extra fields to your index.

The message is: if a query runs slowly, then test if you can speed things up by sorting in node.js, but always do the sorting in mysql first.